# remove label decorator's class at runtime in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am working on one project in zend framework 1.12. for generating decorators I have created one class 'Application_Form_Base' which extends 'Zend_Form'. I have written code in this class in such a manned when I add new element with label decorator in my form  it applies one css class 'field_label' on that label. The problem comes that for some form, I just want to remove this css class of the label at run time. anyone has idea, how can I remove this css class at run time when rending form elements?

Following is my intermediate form class

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Base extends Zend_Form
{

public $elementDecorators = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        array(
                'label',
                array(                          
                        'class' => 'field_label'
                )
        ),
        array(
                array(
                        'row' => 'HtmlTag'
                ),
                array(
                        'tag' => 'div',
                        'class' => 'form-row'
                )
        )
);

public $buttonDecorators = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        array(
                array(
                        'label' => 'HtmlTag'
                ),
                array(
                        'tag' => 'label',
                        'placement' => 'prepend',
                        'class'=>'field_label'
                )
        ),
        array(
                array(
                        'row' => 'HtmlTag'
                ),
                array(
                        'tag' => 'div',
                        'class' => 'form-row'
                )
        )
);

public function loadDefaultDecorators ()
{
    $this->setDecorators(
            array(
                    'FormElements',
                    array(
                            'HtmlTag',
                            array(
                                    'tag' => 'div',
                                    'class' => 'zendForm'
                            )
                    ),
                    'Form'
            ));
}
}
```

following is snippet of my search form

```
class Admin_Form_SubscribeSearch extends Application_Form_Base
{

public function init()
{
    $locale = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate');

    /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */

    $this->setMethod('post');
    $this->setName('searchPackage');

    $this->addElement('text','name',array(
        'label'=>$locale->translate('label_name'),
        'required'=>true,
        'decorators'=> $this->elementDecorators,
        'filters'=>array('StringTrim'),
        'class'=>'',   
    ));
```

following is the html output generated for that form field.

```
<label class="field_label required" for="price">name</label>
```

I want to remove this 'field_label' class when rending form elements in the view. how can I achieve this?

Comment: thanks Florent for making my question's description more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set specific decorator for specific element:

```
$element = $this->getElement('name');
$element->setDecorator(array('Label')); // without additional class
```

Comment: thanks for your comments but I got error when putting this above 2 lines in my form class. error:  "Method setDecorator does not exist". please tell me what I did wrong ? did I put the code in wrong file ?

Comment: this should be `$element->setDecorators(array(relist all decorators needed to render element));` There is no `setDecorator()` only `addDecotrator()`

Comment: @RockyFord where should I put this code exactly? I put in my form's class but it has no effect.